# Turning a <div> content into a $variable in php

Tags: php, html

I have this website were you can order products.
The title of the products you can order are in HTML:

```
   <div class="whatever"> Title </div>
```

I want to retrieve this "title" and set my php variable $product to the value "Title".
I have search a lot on the internet but somehow I am not able to find my answer.
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you looking to CURL a website and extract title from it?

Comment: There are some great tutorials out there. Check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) and [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/). When you get a bit more experienced [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/) this is an invaluable resource. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\DOMDocument->loadHTML();`

Ex:

```
<?php
$doc = new \DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div class="whatever"> Title </div>');
```

View examples here:
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

This is assuming that your source is available to php. It would probably be more pragmatic to extract the value with javascript in the client and send it with the page request. If your app is well structured, the logic that renders the title into the page in the first place is probably where you should be looking to retrieve the information rather than trying to parse the html separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you would like to do this from the client side, you should be using AJAX to achieve this. However, I think you mean that you want to put the HTML in a variable. That is very simple:

```
$variable = "<div class=\"whatever\"> Title </div>";
```

And to output the HTML:

```
echo $variable;
```

You can also add multiple elements to a single variable by concatting.

```
$variable = "";
$variable .= "<div class=\"whatever\"> Title </div>";
$variable .= "<div class=\"whatever\"> Another Title </div>";

echo $variable;
```

If you mean that you want to echo a variable within a dv, that works exactly the same way:

```
<div class="title"><?php echo $product; ?></div>
```

Or better looking:

```
<div class="title"><?= $product; ?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what I am trying to do is the opposite of what you suggested in the second part. 
I would like not to display a variable into a div, but take the value of that div and put it in a variable.
I don't know if that's possible or not?

Comment: It is possible but since that div is displayed client side, you will need to use javascript to achieve it. Can I ask what purpose this has? Maybe I can help you if I understand your reasoning.