# Is there any possible way to copy a whole table from an URL with its content to an another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html-table

I have a WP Plugin generated custom page with a table which has `<table class = "specs-product">` class name. I know how it generates the custom URL, so I can reach it every time I want but I would like to show only this whole table on my template page as well. Is there any copy-paste like solution to this problem or is it harder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution with Curl:**

***(Download: [SimpleHtmlDomParser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download?source=files))***

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $ch1 = curl_init('FirstPageUrl');
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $FirstPage = curl_exec($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);

    $FirstPageHtml = str_get_html($FirstPage);
    $Table = $FirstPageHtml->find('table[class=specs-product]');
    echo $Table;
```

**Solution with Simple Dom Parser:**

***(Download: [SimpleHtmlDomParser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download?source=files))***

```
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('FirstPageUrl',false);
    $Table = $html->find('table[class=specs-product]');
    echo $Table;
```

**Solution with PHP:**

Turn your table into a php variable and pass it to the next page with a session.

[How to turn a Div into a Varaible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468066/turning-a-div-content-into-a-variable-in-php)

[What is a Session?](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)